# Group By in an ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, repeater

I have a set of questions that are grouped first by Parent Questions, and then by Subject.  So basically my aim is to display something like this:-

Subject 1

Parent Question 1

Question 1
Question 2
Question 3

Subject 2

Parent Question 2

Question 4
Question 5
Question 6

At the moment I have the following code :-

```
        List<Questions> questions = new List<Questions>

    questions = GetQuestions().OrderByDescending(x => x.SubjectId)  

        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
    PopulateObject

            QuestionList.Add(Object);
        }

        rptRepeater1.DataSource = QuestionList;
        rptRepeater1.DataBind();
```

and then I have 3 nested repeaters as follows :-

```
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptRepeater1">
                    <%# Eval("SubjectTitle")  %>

                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptRepeater2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("ParentTitle")  %>

                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptRepeater3" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("QuestionTitle")  %>      
                                        <%# Eval("QuestionSummary")  %>  .....          
                                </ItemTemplate>                                
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

At the moment only the Subject is being displayed.

How can I get the list as I wish to display it?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Is this question still open? Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

try to  set dataSource for rptRepeater2 and rptRepeater3 in rptRepeater1_OnItemDataBound

Comment: I cannot get a reference in code for rptRepeater2 and rptRepeater3